# Is it worth answering a question for which an answer has already been accepted?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer, answers

I always wonder, is it worth giving an answer to a question that has already received answers and where one of the answers has been accepted?

If yes, how does it actually help? The asker has already accepted what he thought to be the most convenient answer for him.

**Edit:** I mean, do people bother looking for such questions?

Comment: This doesn't really belong here. But I can answer your question with a recent example: I did exactly this, posting a better answer to a question with an already accepted answer. The author came back and accepted mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202629/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-mac-virtual-key-codes/4642095#4642095. I think it's a great practice, as StackOverflow is as much for posterity as it is for the original poster.

Comment: yes I do, the green checkmark is fine, but its usually something I already tried.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what your value of "worth" is. If you feel you have a better answer and share it, it might be useful to someone that stumbles upon the question in the future. However, it's not as likely that the original asker will mark your answer as accepted or that you will get many votes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's definitely worth it.

Consider, for example, that the OP accepted an answer which appears to be correct, yet has some subtle flaw. In such a case, if you can provide a better answer, by all means, you should do so.

Answer (score 2):

It's only worth it if you can bring something **substantially new, better, more correct or more complete** to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, there is a reason for answering question even if it already has accepted answer. Most often, users will accept answers to increase their accept rate on SO. So most times, the **users are bound to accept an answer which would be near correct answer**. If you give the correct answer, which is better than that accepted answer, there is every chance that the OP can mark your answer as accepted too.

Answer (score 1):

Later on, other people will search and may stumble upon the question.  If you have some new insight, it would help the next people.  Also other answers can be upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it worth, cause each question doesn't have the whole thing same 
please be kind for people who asking for someone's help not for reputation only. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are not trying to compile you question from other questions, just to have chance to be upvoted, this is acceptable by all means.

Someone who has asked the question is by definition a person who seeks for information he currently felt the lack of. Someone who answered the question, and that question had been accepted, is definitely well-willing person, who had provided some useful information.

But this does not automatically means that his answer is the best one.
It is always good if somebody will provide some additional information (or another point of view on the issue).

As for the part "do people look", be pretty sure they do. If you'll inspect the set of highly up-voted questions, you will mention that most of them have quite often a bunch of high-voted answers. It's not that rare that some answer has more votes than accepted one.

Besides, do not forget that any answer, even perfect one, can just become outdated or even contrary to current practices.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of wrong answers on SO, I think adding a correct answer if you believe it to be so is a really good idea.  Unfortunately there are limits to curation regarding answer accuracy which is why its up to the questioner to decide to accept in the first place.  The more right answers on SO the better whether they are the accepted answer or not.